# How to refer to body parts

Tags: artículos, posesivos, cuerpo-humano

I was taught in school that it is incorrect to use possessive pronouns to refer to body parts, and instead to use articles (for example, "me duele **el** estómago"). However, I frequently hear possessive pronouns used (especially in songs). For example, "que me da **su** mano franca" or "llevo a un lado de **mi** piel." Is it correct to use both?

Comment: One thing is an action performed on a body, like lavarme los dientes. Another is to mention a part of a body in another context. Llevo a un lado de mi piel, can be said no other way.  Also, be careful, in English, parts of the body are not body parts. :)

Comment: I'm from Argentina, we say "me duele el estómago", but in Mexico (where I live) it's very common to say "me duele mi estomago". I don't think there is any rule against this, both expressions make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> En español, el artículo adquiere valor posesivo cuando determina a sustantivos que denotan partes o posesiones inherentes o inalienables, como son las partes del cuerpo; así, se dice «Me duele la cabeza» (y no *«mi cabeza»).

In Spanish, the article acquires possessive value when it determines nouns that denote inherent or inalienable parts or possessions, such as parts of the body; thus, it is said "Me duele la cabeza" (and not * "mi cabeza").

<sub>*Answer of the RAE (Real Academia Española) extracted from the same query made in [Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1168495312182419456)*</sub>

In any case, the lyrics of the songs are usually made with terms and syntactic constructions of popular use that do not have to be officially accepted.

Comment: Pero se dice también: Mi cabeza me duele. [o sea, no la pierna]

Comment: Si, hay muchas frases más o menos populares hechas: "lo ví con **mis** propios ojos", "lo sostuve con **mis** brazos", "ella lo siente en lo profundo de **su** corazón"... La RAE recomienda no utilizar ninguna de ellas.